# Finding protocol buffer message type from serialized data

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have some binary data, which was obtained by serializing a google protocol buffer class.
How do I find out, at runtime, the class for which the data was serialized.

For example, suppose i have a **class abc**. I serialized this class abc into binary data.
Is there any way of validating that this binary data was obtained by serializing **class abc,** and not some other class?

Further, if i parse this binary data of class abc by the parse method of **class xyz**, how would I know if the parse was successful.

Comment: If you have control over both ends of the connection you can "cheat" by adding the name of the (outermost) class as a prefix to the Google protocol buffers data. That's what I'm doing, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17923846/253938 .

Comment: Hmm..that would work :D..but sadly I dont have control over the senders side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protobuf does not include any type information on the wire (unless you do that yourself external to protobuf). As such you **cannot** strictly validate that - which is actually a *good* thing, because it means that types are interchangeable and compatible. As long as `class abc` *has a compatible contract* to the other type, it will work. By "compatible" here, I mean: for any field-numbers that are common to both, they have compatible wire-types. If `abc` declares field 4 to be a string, and the other class declares field 4 to be a double-precision number, then it will fail at deserialize.

One other "signal" you could use is the omission of `required` fields: if `abc` always includes field 3, but you get data that *omits* field 3, then it probably isn't an `abc`. Note that protobuf is designed to be version tolerant, though: you can't assume that *extra* fields mean it isn't an `abc`, as it could be that the data is using a later version of the contract, or is using extension fields. Likewise, missing *optional* fields could be missing because *either* they simply chose not to provide a value, *or* that field is not declared on the version of the contract they are using.

Re testing for a successful parse: that will be implementation specific. I would *imagine* that the c++ implementation will have either a return-value to check, or a flag field to check. I don't use that api myself so I cannot say. On some other platforms I would expect an exception to be thrown (java, .net, etc) if there was a critical issue.

Comment: parse functions do return a bool value. But sadly they are returning _true_ in both cases - if I parse using either `class abc` or `class xyz`

Comment: @TusharKoul well, comparing to the rest of my answer: is there anything between `abc` and `xyz` that would make them *incompatible*? The main things here would be a field-number with very different meanings in the two cases. Overall, protobuf adopts the philosophy that you already know what your data is meant to be and *get it right*.

Comment: The question is not of compatibility. I just wanted a validation that the data will be parsed for the correct class. Like you mentioned in the comment, if the class was wrong and the parse returned false, i would know that I'm callig the parse for the wrong class. 
But i guess you _are_ right about the philosophy of protobuf that the class type should be already known.

Comment: @TusharKoul indeed, what I'm trying to demonstrate here is that you **cannot** know that it was the *same* type, but there are some limited occasions when you **can** determine that it was a *different* type - i.e. when there is an actual conflict. The absence of a conflict does not indicate sameness.